# Images do not appear with URL Rewrite

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, isapi

I wrote a rule for URL Rewrite and it works fine, but after I put it in place, the images in the pages no longer appear.

Comment: Please provide the rewrite rules you are using with your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `<base>` tag in the head, to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have addressed your images relatively, which means their addresses will be rewritten accordingly.

For example, if you page at /folder/page.html gets rewritten to /folder/pages/page and you have an image at `image.png` the browser will try to locate it at `/folder/pages/page/image.png` instead of `/folder/image.png`.

To avoid this, either address them using their absolute path, or use a rewrite condition that avoids rewriting URLs that point to existing files or directories.